# query not populating null colomns

Tags: sql

i am having issue with my query.

this query fetches me last 5 weeks data.

```
select z.week,
sum(case when i.severity=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 1
sum(case when i.severity=2 then 1 else 0 end) as 2
sum(case when i.severity=3 then 1 else 0 end) as 3
sum(case when i.severity=4 then 1 else 0 end) as 4
from instance as i
and left outer join year as z on convert(varchar(10),z.date,101)=convert(varchar(10),i.created,101)
and left outer join year as z on convert(varchar(10),z.date,101)=convert(varchar(10),i.closed,101)
where i.group in '%Tools%'
and z.year=2013
and z.week<=6 and z.week>1
```

here there are few weeks in my instance table, where there will be not even an single row. so here im not getting null or zero... instead  the entire row is not at all prompting.

my present output.

```
week | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
---------------------
2  | 0 | 1 | 8 | 5
4  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 9
5  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

but i need output like the below...

```
week | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
---------------------
2  | 0 | 1 | 8 | 5
3  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
4  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 9
5  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
6  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

my question is how t get the zeros for rows not present in the instance table..
kindly guide on this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a right join instead of a left.  If you are wanting some data present in column 1 of your expression but it comes to the RIGHT of a join expression, you need to include it with either a right join or rewrite your from clause to have it first.

EDIT: Here are some simple examples of joins with a simple example:

```
declare @Z table ( dt date, value int);

insert into @Z values ('3-1-2013', 10),('3-4-2013',20);

declare @Y table (dt date, value int);

insert into @Y values ('3-1-2013', 5),('3-3-2013', 30);

select * from @Z  -- @Z table as is
select * from @Y  -- @Y table as is

select *
from @Z z
    inner join @Y y on z.dt = y.dt  -- I only get the values that they both exist on

select *
from @Z z
    left outer join @Y y on z.dt = y.dt  -- I get the values of @Z table regardless if @Y exists or not

select *
from @Z z
    right outer join @Y y on z.dt = y.dt  -- I get the values of @Y table regardless if @Z exists or not, I flipped my logic

select *
from @Z z
    full outer join @Y y on z.dt = y.dt  -- I get all the values of @Z table and @Y regardless of matching rules
```

Comment: i am unable to get the null roes in my output.

Comment: i am unable to get null colomns in my outpur. guide me on this

Comment: Do you have all nulls on both tables you are matching on?  No DATA on either location? If that is a case I would create a third table or object that contains the values manually.  You cannot join that which does not exist.

Comment: in the second table i.e, in instances table.. there is no data.. but in first table i.e, in date.. i got values.

Comment: If you have a 'date' on i or z it should join on a combination of one or the other.  Without seeing your data exactly as it is from the table directly I am not certain what you are doing wrong.  It could be potentially that you are doing two join operations and one is null and the other has values.  Or your predicate saying 'group in 'Tools' ' is limiting the output.  Without seeing your data directly I can only give you self executing examples that may apply to your issue.

Comment: You need to remove part of the predicate then and do the join without the 'i.group in '%Tools%' ' section I am guessing.